# How to transfer file from remote server to local machine using with ssh

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

I have accessed Linux Server on a Windows machine using ssh, created files and am now trying to see if I can transfer the files to my **Windows** local machine without the use if FTP apps. tried using the searching on and using the **scp** command but I feel am using it wrongly. how I can correctly use it or other methods (commands) I can use to achieve my goal.

Comment: How about showing what you did and where (and how exactly) it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not natively support SSH, so you will need to add a client (OpenSSH, Putty, etc.).

I would recommend installing pscp on your Windows computer.  From there, you can use a command like so to "pull" files onto your Windows computer:

```
pscp fred@example.com:/etc/hosts c:\temp\example-hosts.txt
```

This was taken from the pscp documentation:
[link](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu client client supported on Windows when developer mode is activated. Lemme try installing pscp and see how it works. Thanks